# enable/disable asp:dropdownlist using jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Why this code isn't working:

**jquery:**

```
     $("input[id$='rbtlDestination']").change(function(){
            if ($(this).val() == "To Subsidiary:")
                $("input[id$='ddlSubsidiaries']").removeAttr('disabled');
            else
                $("input[id$='ddlSubsidiaries']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     });
```

**html:**

```
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtlDestination" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" CssClass="FormatRadioButtonListItems">
                <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="To Work">To Work</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="To Subsidiary:">To Subsidiary:</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>

    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubsidiaries" runat="server" Width="160px" Enabled="false" 
                    DataSourceID="odsSubsidiaries" DataTextField="Subsidiary" 
                    DataValueField="IdSubsidiary">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

**Rendered:**

```
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rbtlDestination" class="FormatRadioButtonListItems">
<input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rbtlDestination_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rbtlDestination" value="To Work" checked="checked" />
<label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rbtlDestination_0">To Work</label>
<input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rbtlDestination_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rbtlDestination" value="To Subsidiary:" />
<label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rbtlDestination_1">To Subsidiary:</label></span>


<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlSubsidiaries" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlSubsidiaries" disabled="disabled" style="width:160px;">
<option selected="selected" value="2">Sub A</option>
<option value="1">Sub B</option>
```

Comment: `$("#rbtlDestination")`

Comment: @user790454 didn't work

Comment: Can you show me rendered html of radiobuttonlist and dropdownlist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".FormatRadioButtonListItems input[type=radio]").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "To Subsidiary:")
            $(".ddlSubsidiaries").prop("disabled", false)
        else
            $(".ddlSubsidiaries").prop("disabled", true)
    });
});
```

**Asp.net**

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtlDestination" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" CssClass="FormatRadioButtonListItems">
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="To Work">To Work</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="To Subsidiary:">To Subsidiary:</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubsidiaries" runat="server" Width="160px" Enabled="false" 
                DataSourceID="odsSubsidiaries" DataTextField="Subsidiary" 
                DataValueField="IdSubsidiary" CssClass="ddlSubsidiaries">
</asp:DropDownList>
```